# Query SQL para relación única

Tags: sql

Tengo dos tablas, Camisa y Pantalon.

```
ID_CAMISA  CAMISA           PESO_GR   ID_TIENDA
1          lino blanca      210       1
2          algodon naranja  290       1
3          seda negra       260       1

ID_PANTALON  PANTALON           PESO_GR  ID_TIENDA
1            tela azul marino   470      1
2            pana marron claro  730      1
```

Quiero que una única camisa este asociado a un único pantalón . Mi resultado tendría que quedar así:

```
ID_CAMISA  PANTALON         
1          tela azul marino 
2          pana marron claro
3
```

¿Cómo tendría que ser mi query?

Comment: Si quieres una relacion de uno a uno, entonces solo necesitarias tenerlo en la misma tabla, si pones los 4 datos en la misma tabla entonces queria unico, ademas si quieres que estrictamente sus combinaciones sean unicas deberas de poner una CONSTRAINT para que la combinacion de los registros sea unico

Comment: Y cual es la diferencia entre el query resultado y la tabla pantalon? solamente que tiene los id de las camisas? y la relacion es id_camisa id_pantalon?? esa relacion es muy rara... no deberias tener una tabla que una la camisa y el pantalon?

Comment: Perdón, ahí corregí las tablas. Este es un ejemplo sencillo, que encontré. Tengo dos tablas temporales, del resultado de un extenso query.

Answer (score 1):

al no tener una tabla de relación entre las entidades, creo que el query podrias realizarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
;WITH cx AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by c.id_camisa)  as row_id
        ,c.id_camisa
    FROM
        dbo.camisa AS c
), px AS(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by p.id_pantalon)    as row_id
        ,p.pantalon
    FROM
        dbo.pantalon AS p
)

SELECT
    cx.id_camisa,isnull(px.pantalon,'') pantalon
FROM
    cx
    LEFT JOIN px ON cx.row_id = px.row_id
```

Los row_id seran los que nos daran la relacion ficticia sobre las tablas, despues relacionamos los row_id de una columna con los de la otra columna, y hacemos el left join sobre ambas columnas, para que puedas obtener el resultado que deseas, saludos.